# How to decrypt .jpg files of comics app in a C Program?

Tags: c, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt jpg images of comics I purchased in my comic reader app on android but neither I can view them (after copying from SD card to Windows desktop) nor can I convert them to pdf to read on my desktop.

I see a lot of data before start of jpg header FF D8, and am confused.

01 00 00 00 2D 82 00 00 28 00 00 00 80 47 88 47 80 48 08 48 00 48 08 48 00 48 88 47 00 48 88 47 00 48 88 47 00 48 08 48 EF 4F 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C8 E3 E4 E4 03 3A AB F3 0F DE 05 14 33 C9 82 B8 32 72 8F 20 67 10 7D 08 45 09 99 C6 61 1B 30 C4 D4 15 6F F1 8C 65 05 C1 FF D8 FF E0

Here are examples of those encrypted images: https://www.mediafire.com/view/4tnc45xppeazy1c/09.jpg https://www.mediafire.com/file/u0z57slaar4k9ln/10.jpg

Is there a way of decrypting these in a C Program ?

I tried getting information in JPEGsnoop, it stops at Unknown marker [0xFF02] From the header information it is jpeg file, but parsing stops abruptly. It may be embedded jpeg's in custom format.

```
*** Marker: SOS (Start of Scan) (xFFDA) ***
  OFFSET: 0x00000152
Scan header length = 12
  Number of img components = 3
    Component[1]: selector=0x01, table=0(DC),0(AC)
    Component[2]: selector=0x02, table=1(DC),0(AC)
    Component[3]: selector=0x03, table=1(DC),0(AC)
  Spectral selection = 0 .. 0
  Successive approximation = 0x01

 NOTE: Scan parsing doesn't support this SOF mode.

*** Marker: ??? (Unknown) (xFF02) ***
OFFSET: 0x00004806
    WARNING: Unknown marker [0xFF02]
  Stopping decode
  Use [Img Search Fwd/Rev] to locate other valid embedded JPEGs
```

While opening in photoshop loads only a part of jpeg image or shows error "Could not complete your request because of a problem parsing the JPEG data". While in android app first a thumbnail image loads, then panels are loaded as detailed images, but all information is contained in one single jpeg file. 
Or if there is already a software that can fix extra data in these files.

Comment: did you try decompiling the app and see what it does with the files?

Comment: decompiling the app is beyond my skill level.

Comment: Basically the app loads a low resolution full image then it loads portions of image panel by panel. Probably image coordinates for panels is marked.

Comment: Some JPEGs have embedded thumbnails that have the same SOF magic/EOF as the full-resolution image, so there may be some sort of mix-up with that. Unless you unpack the application, decompile it, and/or view its contents dynamically in memory (scanning for JPEG SOF/EOF and attempting to rebuild files manually via hex editor, Python, etc.), what you're looking to accomplish may simply not be possible using the samples you've provided...maybe. I haven't looked at the files, so I'm not sure. The app may also be rendering JPEG output (based on zoom) from a different lossless image format, etc.

Comment: For now I have solved the problem by running it in virtual android RemixOSPlayer and taking screenshots from Windows and batch cropping the images. I wanted to extract full resolution single images, but may be it is a embedded image file with a low resolution full image.